# Rendering JSONP in HTML format on Java Servlet response

Tags: java, jquery, servlets, cross-domain, jsonp

I am having a problem. I have a form submit that uses jQuery JSONP to make a call BACK to my servlet. This code is embedded in another domain, hence the usage.

**Here is my form submit AJAX:**

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script language='Javascript' type='text/javascript'>
$(\"#form1\").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this),
        choice2 = $form.find( 'input[name=\"personChoice\"]' ).val(),
        url = $form.attr( 'action' ),
    $.ajax({
            data: {choice:choice2},
            url: url,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: 'callback',
            jsonpCallback: 'updatePage'
    });
});
function updatePage(renderHTML) { 
    alert(renderHTML);
}
</script>
```

I can confirm in my Java servlet that the request.getParameter("callback") is populated with updatePage. What I need to do is send back a response in JSONP format within the Java Servlet. How does one do that? I have something really simple like this at the moment:

**Java Servlet code:**

```
        response.setContentType("text/javascript");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String renderHTML = "{ renderHTML = 'Successful'}";

        out.println(renderHTML);
```

I also tried JSON content type response, the alert in my javascript updatePage doesn't get called.

What is the trick with Java servlet's and response back on a jsonpCallback???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JSONP response must be wrapped inside a function call which is specified in request with callback.

Something like

```
callback({ renderHTML = 'Successful'});
```

This should usually be taken care at a filter.

Answer (score 0):

The jsonpCallback property is not what you think it is. It's a string (or a function returning a string) which jquery will use as part of the request URL. You can set it to `false` if you don't need that functionality. [See the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)

You should use the 'success' property to set the response handler. 
Something like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        data: {choice:choice2},
        url: url,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'callback',
        jsonpCallback: false,
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert("error");
        },
        success: updatePage
        });
```

Also, the best content-type to use for JSONP is `application/javascript`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for comment - I do need that callback string to trigger a semi-filter. I've been reading about the success ajax property - let me try that out.

Comment: Hmm. This is partly inexperience with this, but when I make that jsonpCallback, I am hoping to have that callback parameter as a 'trigger' for a filter. When I see a callback parameter (regardless of what it is), I want to render some JSON response BACK to that callback method (this case updatePage). I can see alerts I through into that method, so I know the call is coming back. I think the problem I have now is how do I take a full html tagged string and pass it back in the response to update a div? Do I need to use Stringfy?

Comment: One last comment - That content type seems to have fixed one problem I had. Thanks!